# Haskell component-by-component addition

Tags: haskell, lambda

I am trying do to the component-by-component addition of a list of tuples with the use of higher functions. The result should be the (sum of the first component, sum on the second component).

```
sumPointwise    :: Num a => [(a,a)] -> (a,a)
sumPointwise tl = (sumPw1, sumPw2)                         -- 42:1
  where sumPw1  = foldr (\ x y -> (fst x) + (fst y)) 0 tl
        sumPw2  = foldr (\ x y -> (snd x) + (snd y)) 0 tl
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Couldn't match type `a' with `(a, b0)'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for sumPointwise :: Num a => [(a, a)] -> (a, a)
      at .hs:42:1
In the first argument of `fst', namely `y'
In the second argument of `(+)', namely `(fst y)'
In the expression: (fst x) + (fst y)
```

It seems like the lambda function is wrong. But I don't get it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of [`foldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3afoldr) is aggregate value: `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`. So, your expressions should look like

```
sumPw1 = foldr (\ x s -> (fst x) + s) 0 tl
```

More succinct way of solving your task is

```
sumPointwise tl = let (xs, ys) = unzip tl in (sum xs, sum ys)
```

Comment: Well if you are looking for succinct then perhaps `(sum *** sum) . unzip`.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson + `import Control.Arrow` :)